# Round up the current time as nearest 30 min interval Obj c

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

My Picker Settings:

- time mode only
- 30 mins interval
- current time
- Get picker value(below code) after a button action:

  ```
  //Begin time
  if(date_formate)
  date_formate=nil;

  date_formate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [date_formate setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

   txtfldBeginTime.text=[date_formate stringFromDate:time_picker.date];
  ```

Problem:

- current time is 6:17 PM
- The picker starts and displaying from 6:00 PM.
- When get the picker value without any scroll in picker. It returns 6:17 PM.
- When get the picker value with some scroll in picker and set the time where its starts(6:00 PM). Then, it returns 6:00 PM as normal.

Proposing:

1.

- if the current time is above 5:30 and below 6:00 means, then the picker starts from 6:00.
- Otherwise, the current time is above 6:00 and below 6:30 means, then the picker starts from 6:30.

  2. when get the picker value without any scroll, the return value should be initial value of picker. That is, if the picker starts from 6:30 means then the picker return value be 6:30.

Comment: If you don't know how to round a number to some multiple boundary you should take a mathematics class.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the formula to round up to nearest 30 minute

```
int remainder = currentMinute % 30;
int rounded = currentMinute + 30-remainder;

// if current minute is 17
// remainder = 17 % 30 == 17
// rounded = 17 + 30-17 == 30

// if current minute is 56
// remainder = 56 % 30 == 26
// rounded = 56+30-26== 60
```

EDIT: correct the modulo operator from \ to %

EDIT2: sorry the formula i post previously was incorrect. This should be the correct answer

EDIT 3: full code

```
- (NSDate *)roundUpToNearestHalfHour:(NSDate *)value {
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitCalendar fromDate:value];
    NSInteger minute = [comp minute];
    int remainder = minute % 30;
    int rounded = minute + 30 - remainder;

    [comp setMinute:rounded];

    return [comp date];
}
```

Comment: please post the answer which tells any pre-defined methods or delegate to get the answer.

Comment: How to split the minute from current time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this way

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    DoneCancelNumberPadToolbar *toolbar = [[DoneCancelNumberPadToolbar alloc] initWithTextField:self.startTime];
    toolbar.delegateLocal = self;
    self.startTime.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    self.endTime.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;

    self.pickerStartTime = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self.pickerStartTime.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [self.pickerStartTime setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"]];
    [self.pickerStartTime setMinuteInterval:30];
    [self.pickerStartTime addTarget:self action:@selector(dateStartIsChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.startTime.inputView = self.pickerStartTime;
}

- (void) dateStartIsChanged {
    NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitHour|NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitCalendar fromDate:self.pickerStartTime.date];

    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];

    self.startTime.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:[comp date]];
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation, even though the code might work, will raise the answer value for a long term.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for something like @Tien Dinh's answer but in Swift (Swift 4).

```
func roundUpToNearestQuarterHour(date: Date) -> Date{


    var comp = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)

    let minute = comp.minute
    let remainder = minute % 30;
    let rounded = minute + 30 - remainder;

    comp.setValue(rounded, for: .minute)

    return comp.date

}
```